# Defining fr for grid only for first and second child of ul

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am creating a navigation for a website with `ul li`. There are currently 7 links in it. I've set the display of `ul` to grid with `repeat(7,1fr)`. However I want the first and second `li` to be .5fr and 1.5fr. How can I do it?

```
nav ul {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7,1fr);
}
```

How I want it to be.

```
nav ul{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: .5fr 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid-template-columns: .5fr 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` is correct too. You can *shorten* it to `grid-template-columns: .5fr 1.5fr repeat(5, 1fr)` or `grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr repeat(5, 2fr)` - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr repeat(5, 2fr);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this :

```
nav ul{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: .5fr 1.5fr repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

there is no trick here, it works fine

Comment: Thanks for you answer!

Comment: pleasure :) I didn't know about grid-templates uses before this post so thanks !